# Sql loader - second enclosure string not present

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am loading a .csv file data into oracle table through sql loader. One of the fields has a new line character (CRLF) in its data and so, am getting the below error:

second enclosure string not present

This is my control file

```
load data
characterset UTF8
infile 'C:\Users\lab.csv'
truncate 
into table test_labinal
fields terminated by ";" optionally enclosed by '"' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
      ( 

    STATEMENT_STATUS ,
    MANDATORY_TASK ,
    COMMENTS CHAR(9999)  "SubStr(:Comments, 0, 1000)"
)
```

The field COMMENTS has a new line character in one of its records. Can any one suggest a solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best way to load the .csv files with fields containing newline and comma.Please run the macro over the .csv file and then load using sqlloader

```
Sub remove()
Dim row As Integer

Dim oxcel As Excel.Application
Dim wbk As Excel.Workbook
Set oxcel = New Excel.Application
Set wbk = oxcel.Workbooks.Open("filename.csv", 0, True)
row = 0
With oxcel
.ActiveSheet.Select
 Do
 row = row + 1
    'Assume first column is PK and so checking for empty pk to find the number of rows
  Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(row, 1)) Or IsNull(Cells(row, 1))
  Range(Cells(1, 24), Cells(row - 1, 24)).Select
  For Each oneCell In Selection
  oneCell.Value = Application.Substitute(Application.Substitute 
 (Application.Substitute  (CStr(oneCell.Value), vbLf, vbCr), vbCr, "-"),",","-")

    Next oneCell

    End With
     End Sub
```

It's running perfect for me.

Answer (score 5):

If your last field is always present (though `trailing nullcols` suggests it isn't) and you have some control over the formatting, you can use the [`CONTINUEIF`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/ldr_control_file.htm#SUTIL1100) directive to treat the second line as part of the same logical record.

If the `comments` field is always present and enclosed in double-quotes then you can do:

```
...
truncate
continueif last != x'22'
into table ...
```

Which would handle data records like:

```
S;Y;"Test 1"
F;N;"Test 2"
P;Y;"Test with
new line"
P;N;""
```

Or if you always have a delimiter after the comments field, whether it is populated or not:

```
...
truncate
continueif last != ';'
into table ...
```

Which would handle:

```
S;Y;Test 1;
F;N;"Test 2";
P;Y;Test with
new line;
P;N;;
```

Both ways will load the data as:

```
S M COMMENTS
- - ------------------------------
S Y Test 1
F N Test 2
P Y Test withnew line
P N
```

But this loses the new line from the data. To keep that you need the terminating field delimiter to be present, and instead of `CONTINUEIF` you can change the record separator using the [stream record format](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/ldr_concepts.htm#SUTIL3315):

```
...
infile 'C:\Users\lab.csv' "str ';\n'"
truncate
into table ...
```

The `"str ';\n'"` defines the terminator as the combination of the field terminator and a new line character. Your split comment only has that combination on the final line. With the same data file as the previous version, this gives:

```
S M COMMENTS
- - ------------------------------
S Y Test 1
F N Test 2
P Y Test with
    new line

P N

4 rows selected.
```

Since you're on Windows you might have to include `\r` in the format as well, e.g. `"str ';\r\n'"`, but I'm not able to check that.

Comment: @Alex...Hi Alex. Thanks for your reply. As you said, the comments column may contain NULL values and that's the reason i went for TRAILING NULCOLS. From the given options, the 1st one(continueif last != x'22') is working fine . But, now the problem is, the column without newline character is not loading.

Comment: @Alex...Hi Alex, these are my sample data for 3 columns...................... aaaa 300 cav4VO;23.07.2010;280-VIN VALIDATED;Rework done as requested (L928 91002 000 C2, Vers. 007)

Comment: @VinodChelladurai - can your comment values (including null) always be enclosed in quotes, or have a terminator afterwards, and/or be in a different order? That sample data seems to have 4 columns, but the comment field doesn't seem to have anything that would let you distinguish a split entry.

Comment: @Alex....As far as i analysed the data, the comments field does not have any terminator afterwards and it does not necessary to be enclosed with quotes always....moreover, we have this .csv file for along time and i have been asked to laod this sqlloader only ver recently. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Alex...Hope u understood my reply

Comment: @VinodChelladurai - I did, but with that formatting I don't see how you can get SQL*Loader to guess which lines are split. I think you might have to edit the file to make it parseable; how many lines are there, and how many are split? I suspect this will be a manual process; you could probably automate it by counting delimiters but it gets complicated when the (quoted) comments include those. If there are a small number of split entries doing it by hand might be faster. (e.g. add a delimiter to the end of every line, then go through and remove them from the split lines).

Comment: You're basically trying to make SQL*Loader do that process for you, which doesn't seem reasonable. You could look at an external table instead but that will have the same issues.

Comment: @Alex..Hi alex..there were around 4000 lines in .csv file...that is ok...But now..am facing the problem of no terminator found after TERMINATED and ENCLOSED field when i did ur solution.

Comment: @VinodChelladurai - I can't see your file, you'll have to check the format of every line. Hmm, did you include `\r` in the `str` format, if that's the solution you're referring to?

Comment: @Alex...Hi Alex...I got it somehow after editing my .cs file...Now, when i load with 4 records,nothing got loaded...At the same time,log file whoing no errors...it's just showing 0 rows loaded...i did not find anything in bad and discarded files too..Any idea from ur side???...thank you

Comment: @Vinod - I guess your `str` isn't matching anything now so it sees no rows at all, maybe? Though it should still see at least one I think, unless the file is empty. Sorry, not sure what to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

```
load data
characterset UTF8
infile 'C:\Users\lab.csv'
truncate 
into table test_labinal
fields terminated by ";" optionally enclosed by '"' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
      ( 

    STATEMENT_STATUS ,
    MANDATORY_TASK ,
    COMMENTS CHAR(9999)  "SubStr(REPLACE(REPLACE(:Comments,CHR(13)),CHR(10)), 0, 1000)"
)
```

Note:  The `CHR(13)` is the ASCII character for "carriage return" and the `CHR(10)` is the ASCII character for "new line".  Using the Oracle PL/SQL `REPLACE` command without a replacement value will remove any "carriage return" and/or "new line" character that is embedded in your data.  Which is probably the case because the comment field is the last field in your CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace(replace(column_name, chr(10)), chr(13))` to remove newline charactors or `regexp_replace(column_name, '\s+')` to remove non printable charactors during loading

Comment: @San...Hi Thanks for your reply. Replace is not working. and i used the regexp_replace as it is like in your comment. No luck...:(