# External table truncates trailing whitespace while reading from file

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, external-tables

I'm trying to load the file contents to an external table. While doing this, trailing spaces are truncated.

```
'CREATE TABLE ' || rec.ext_table_name || ' (ROW_DATA VARCHAR2(4000)) ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL ' ||
     '(TYPE ORACLE_LOADER DEFAULT DIRECTORY ' || rec.dir_name || ' ACCESS ' || 'PARAMETERS (RECORDS ' ||
     'DELIMITED by NEWLINE NOBADFILE NODISCARDFILE ' ||
     'FIELDS REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS (ROW_DATA POSITION(1:4000) char)) LOCATION (' || l_quote ||
     'temp.txt' || l_quote || ')) REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED'
```

For example, with `B` representing a blank space, my file has:

```
Line1sometextBBBBBBB
```

My external table reads that as just:

```
Line1sometext
```

I want the file to be loaded with blanks too. How can I stop it removing the trailing whitespace?

**Current Problem is :**

if file has:

> "this is a test value with
>
> "

```
 ^   this new line is also a part of the row_data.
```

[image: the problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [a *`trim_spec`* clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_params.htm#SUTIL1411), specifically here `NOTRIM`, to change the default field trimming behaviour:

```
... FIELDS REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS (ROW_DATA POSITION(1:4000) char NOTRIM)) LOCATION (...
                                                                            ^^^^^^
```

Quick demo:

```
create table t42_ext (
  row_data varchar2(4000)
)
organization external
(
  type oracle_loader default directory mydir access parameters
  (
    records delimited by newline nobadfile nodiscardfile
    fields reject rows with all null fields
    (
      row_data position(1:4000) char notrim
    )
  )
  location ('temp.txt')
)
reject limit unlimited;

Table T42_EXT created.

select '<'|| row_data ||'>' from t42_ext;

'<'||ROW_DATA||'>'                                                             
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Line1sometext       >
```

Comment: the records in external tables takes the new line characters also.. Is there any possibility to trim new line alone

Comment: I dont want to use substr..since my file is around 1GB , it affects performance

Comment: Not sure what you mean... isn't the `records delimited by newline` taking care of that?

Comment: yes it should, but it is not... updated the question

Comment: Sorry, still don't really understand. You have values that split onto multiple lines, enclosed by double quotes? You should really ask a new question for this. (I have a feeling I've looked at something similar before but can't immediately find it).

Comment: @theRoot - I might be thinking about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21332278/266304). But that may not quite match your formatting. Depends if the final enclosure is always on a new line, perhaps.

Comment: i used double quotes to refer value in row_data

Comment: Please ask a new question. You may be be able to use continueif but you need to explain a bit more, and you shouldn't be expanding the scope of this question.

Comment: added a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222370/removing-eol-delimiter-from-inserting-into-external-table-oracle