# removing EOL delimiter from inserting into external table -oracle

Tags: oracle, file, end-of-line, external-tables

I have included **notrim** for **rowdata** column in external table as suggesterd by Alex (This is a continuation of  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013530/external-table-truncates-trailing-whitespace-while-reading-from-file) question,),

**But now End of Line character is also appending at the rowdata column**, I mean , End of line (CR-LF) is also joins at the end of rowdata.

I don't want to use substr() or translate() , since file size is around 1GB,

My external table creation process :

```
'CREATE TABLE ' || rec.ext_table_name || ' (ROW_DATA VARCHAR2(4000)) ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL ' ||
     '(TYPE ORACLE_LOADER DEFAULT DIRECTORY ' || rec.dir_name || ' ACCESS ' || 'PARAMETERS (RECORDS ' ||
     'DELIMITED by NEWLINE NOBADFILE NODISCARDFILE ' ||
     'FIELDS REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS (ROW_DATA POSITION(1:4000) char)) LOCATION (' || l_quote ||
     'temp.txt' || l_quote || ')) REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED'
```

Is there any other paramenter I can add , to remove the End-of-line character. Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

My file :

> Some first line with spaces at end
>       Some second line with spaces at end

My Ext table :

> ```
> Some first line with spaces at end    <EOL>
> Some second line with spaces at end   <EOL>
> ```

to be more clear , I will explain in java (when I assign column values to string , it is something like below),

without notrim :

```
rowdata[1]="Some first line with spaces at end";
rowdata[2]="Some second line with spaces at end";
```

with notrim:

```
rowdata[1]="Some first line with spaces at end    \n";
rowdata[2]="Some second line with spaces at end   \n";
```

what I want it to be :

```
rowdata[1]="Some first line with spaces at end    ";
rowdata[2]="Some second line with spaces at end   ";
```

**the delimiter is also a part of rowdata, since no trim is specified.**

**EDIT2:**

> Line-Endings : CRLF

Platform :

> Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit
>
> Production PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
>
> "CORE   12.1.0.1.0  Production" TNS for **Solaris**: Version 12.1.0.1.0 -
>
> Production NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production

**SELECT DUMP(ROW_DATA,1016) FROM  EXT_TABLE WHERE ROWNUM = 1;**

> Typ=1 Len=616 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8:
>   41,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,31,30,30,30,30,37,36,36,36,44,30,30,30,30,31,32,35,30,38,31,36,32,35,30,38,31,36,31,33,34,37,30,39,44,42,20,41,30,36,31,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,32,30,30,4d,59,52,20,32,5a,20,30,31,36,30,30,30,31,32,31,32,33,34,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,52,49,42,46,50,58,30,30,30,31,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,31,30,36,32,38,30,31,30,32,30,30,47,20,20,20,20,53,20,20,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,4e,39,32,37,32,20,20,20,20,20,20,30,30,30,30,30,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,30,30,39,39,38,54,45,53,54,52,52,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,54,45,53,54,4f,50,44,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,54,45,53,54,54,52,41,4e,53,49,44,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,54,45,53,54,52,52,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,54,45,53,54,4f,50,44,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,54,45,53,54,54,52,41,4e,53,49,44,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,d

**Len should be 615**

Comment: Please include an example file, how that currently appears in your external table, and how you want it to appear (all as formatted text if possible rather than images). In the comments on the earlier question is seemed like you wanted to keep the newline if the row spanned more than one line in the file, but now I'm not sure, and it isn't clear if there is a way to identify the start of a real new line in your data.

Comment: The `DELIMITED by NEWLINE` ought to take care of that? What line endings does your file have - CRLF or just one of CR or LF; which platform is your database on (Windows/Linux); and does your row data end up with just LF (\n)? You can use the `dump()` function to check what is actually in a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file line endings are CRLF (suggesting the file is created in Windows?), but your database is running on Solaris. As [the  documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-91CC2060-FA18-4246-BC3F-82154FF4FA5B.htm#SUTIL1383) says:

> If DELIMITED BY NEWLINE is specified, then the actual value used is platform-specific. On UNIX platforms, NEWLINE is assumed to be "\n". On Windows operating systems, NEWLINE is assumed to be "\r\n".

As your database platform is Unix it's only using the LF (`\n`) as the record delimiter. You can either change the delimiter in your file, or change the `terminated by` clause to look for the Windows line-ending:

```
,,,
records delimited by "\r\n" nobadfile ...
```

If you might get files with either type of line ending and can't control that, you could add a [preprocessor step](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-73A6DA8D-EA78-4B9B-BAB3-0C99BF190A50.htm#SUTIL1385) to strip any that do exist. If you create an executable script file, either in the same directory as the file or (as Oracle recommends) in a different Oracle-accessible directory, say called `remove_cr` which contains:

```
/usr/bin/sed -e "s/\\r$//" $1
```

you can add a call to that in your external table definition, and keep the `newline` temrinator:

```
...
records delimited by newline nobadfile nodiscardfile
preprocessor 'remove_cr'
...
```

Make sure you read the the security warnings in the documentation though.

Demo with a `temp.txt` file with CRLF line endings:

```
create table t42_ext (
  row_data varchar2(4000)
)
organization external
(
  type oracle_loader default directory d42 access parameters
  (
    records delimited by newline nobadfile nodiscardfile
    preprocessor 'remove_cr'
    fields reject rows with all null fields
    (
      row_data position(1:4000) char notrim
    )
  )
  location ('temp.txt')
)
reject limit unlimited;

select '<'|| row_data ||'>' from t42_ext;

'<'||ROW_DATA||'>'                                                             
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Line1sometext       >                                                          
<Line2sometext       >                                                          
<Line3sometext       >
```

Comment: No, you're saying that the file will have both characters. If you try to load a file that only has LF it'll all try to go into a single row. The file format has to be consistent.

Comment: If you might get either file type and need to handle both, you *could* add a preprocessor script that strips CR if it's there.

Comment: delimited by "\r\n" works good...but why dos2unix is not converting file format?

Comment: @theRoot - no idea how you're calling it; not sure that will work in a preprocessor clause. See my last edit for something that might.