# SQL*Loader cannnot load a CSV file that contains multiple lines in one field

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a CSV file that I'm trying to load into an Oracle table, using SQL*Loader:

```
a, ab, abcdefg
b, bc, bcdefghij
c, cd, cdefghijk-lmnop
orstuv
wxyz
d, de, defghijk
```

On row "c" the 3rd column has multiple lines, and when we load this row with `sqlldr` it cannot load this column into the table - it puts it into the bad file.

I tried to include the quote string for some column like this

```
a, ab, "abcdefg"
b, bc, "bcdefghij"
c, cd, "cdefghijk-lmnop
orstuv
wxyz"
d, de, "defghijk"
```

I tried the control file in many formats, including:

```
load data
CHARACTERSET TH8TISASCII
infile '/data/csv/test3.txt'
APPEND 
PRESERVE BLANKS
into table ITEM
fields terminated by ","
TRAILING NULLCOLS
( col1,
  col2,
  col3,
  col4)
```

and:

```
load data
CHARACTERSET TH8TISASCII
infile '/data/csv/test3.txt' "str '\n'"
APPEND 
PRESERVE BLANKS
into table ITEM
fields terminated by ","
TRAILING NULLCOLS
( col1,
  col2,
  col3,
  col4)
```

and:

```
load data
CHARACTERSET TH8TISASCII
infile '/data/csv/test3.txt'
APPEND 
PRESERVE BLANKS
into table ITEM
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"'   
TRAILING NULLCOLS
( col1,
  col2,
  col3,
  col4)
```

and:

```
load data
CHARACTERSET TH8TISASCII
infile '/data/csv/test3.txt'
APPEND 
PRESERVE BLANKS
into table ITEM
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '\n' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
( col1,
  col2,
  col3,
  col4)
```

But it still doesn't work.

How can I load data from that CSV format?

---

According to Gary_W recommended
I tried to add the "str x'0D'" and data can load into the column correctly
but it just load only the first row of the CSV file and return the log successfully as below

```
load data
CHARACTERSET TH8TISASCII
infile '/data/csv/b.csv' "str x'0D'"
APPEND
PRESERVE BLANKS
into table ITEM2
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
( col1,
  col2,
  col3,
  col4
)


--Sample CSV file
c, cd, "cdefghijk-lmnop
orstuv
wxyz"
,c
a, ab, "abcdefg", a
b, bc, "bcdefghij", b
d, de, "defghijk",d


--sql loader command
sqlldr USER/PASSWORD readsize=2000000000 bindsize=2000000000 control=file_pointing2.ctl > /data/csv/sqlldr.log

###########################LOG########################
Table ITEM:
1 Row successfully loaded.
0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.

there have only 1 record.
###########################OUT_PUT########################
col1| col2|         col3            | col4
cd  | cd  |efghijk-lmnoporstuvwxyz  | c

but if I remove the option "str x'0D'", in a case of the normal CSV format all row can load currently expect the abnormal row.

load data
CHARACTERSET TH8TISASCII
infile '/data/csv/b.csv' "str x'0D'"
APPEND
PRESERVE BLANKS
into table ITEM2
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
( col1,
  col2,
  col3,
  col4
)
--Sample CSV file
c, cd, "cdefghijk-lmnop
orstuv
wxyz"
,c
a, ab, "abcdefg", a
b, bc, "bcdefghij", b
d, de, "defghijk",d



--sql loader command
sqlldr USER/PASSWORD readsize=2000000000 bindsize=2000000000 control=file_pointing2.ctl > /data/csv/sqlldr.log


there have 4 records.but the record 1(col3) is not correct
###########################OUT_PUT########################
col1| col2|         col3            | col4
c   | cd  |efghijk-lmnop            | c
a   | ab  |abcdefg                  | a
b   | bc  |bcdefghij                | b
d   | de  |defghijk                 | d
```

Comment: Have you attempted to re-save your CSV so that each field is also encased in quotes (look through the program's options on how to save CSVs)?

Comment: Dear BLaZuRE,

 I tried to re-save the CSV file and include Quotes string column but it still doesn't work.

Thanks & Best Regards,
POPs

Comment: If you now have your file with each field in double-quotes, please edit your question to show that, and the control file you're currently using. Have you tried using [the `continueif` directive](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21334074/266304)?

Comment: Thank you, Alex, I already edit my question but the file formatting is difficult to manage.

Comment: OK, but none of your control file examples have `continueif`; did you try that, as shown in the old answer I linked to? ([You can read more about it in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_control_file.htm#SUTIL1100))

Comment: I notice on the first line there is a carriage return after the quote and before the comma.  Is that how it is in the actual data?  Can you post actual data? Are there really spaces after the commas or could they be control characters? Can you look at this data in a hex editor and see if other unexpected control characters are in there messing things up?  I wonder if different character sets are a problem?  Just throwing out some different things to check.

Answer (score 1):

Put double-quotes around the third column and you'll need to use the streaming clause on the INFILE line to tell sqlldr the carriage return is the end of record character so line feeds are ignored inside of the double quotes:

```
infile '/data/csv/test3.txt' "str x'0D'"
```

Since I already explained it all in this post, please have a look there for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37216660/2543416

Comment: Thank you So much Gary_W. I tried to add this option that you recommend and that record can load into the table successfully but after that, it was stopped, it was not loaded another Recodes into the table.

Comment: More info on "stopped"?  Any info in the log file?

Comment: It was downloaded successfully only the 1st row of csv file
and return the log complete and no error. I do not know why that ignore the other rows.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LOG Table ITEM:
  1 Rows successfully loaded.
  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
  0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.

Comment: You'll have to show the control file and the command line too.  Please do it in the original post as the comment section does not allow for formatting. I noticed you have fields terminated by semi-colons in the control file but the data shows they should be commas. Be sure to correct that.

Comment: Thank you Gary_W I already updated information on the original post